# Linux script sort and group without separator

Tags: shell, sorting, sum

Input is given as :

```
10001123
20001234
30002111
40003111
50004000
```

Requirement:
Sort character from 2 to 5
Group by character from 2 to 5
Sum character 6 to 8
Only display line with character 6 to 8 > 0

Expected output is given as :

```
10001357
30002111
40003111
```

Comment: What is your question and can you please include code you tried so far?

Comment: Most of the shell script I found is to sort and group data with separator (e.g. csv).
But is it possible to give the expected output to fit the above requirements?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, from what I comprehend. For example, only display lines with characters 5 to 7 > 0. All lines have 5-7 characters > 0. `50004000`'s 5-7 characters are `400`, and that's > 0. So why is it not in the output?

Comment: What is your "group by" condition? Your input data only contains unique sort keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed -r 's/(.)(....)(...)/\1 \2 \3/' file | awk '{if (!($2 in a))a[$2]=$1; b[$2]+=$3;} END{for (i in b) if (b[i]>0)print a[i],i,b[i];}' | sort -nk2 | sed 's/ //g'
10001357
30002111
40003111
```

#### How it works

Let's break the command into parts.

First is the sed command which separates our groups by spaces:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.)(....)(...)/\1 \2 \3/' file
1 0001 123
2 0001 234
3 0002 111
4 0003 111
5 0004 000
```

The second part is awk which does the summing:

```
awk '{if (!($2 in a))a[$2]=$1; b[$2]+=$3;} END{for (i in b) if (b[i]>0)print a[i],i,b[i];}'
```

The output of awk looks like:

```
1 0001 357
3 0002 111
4 0003 111
```

Next is sort which makes sure that our output is in the desired order:

```
sort -nk2
```

Lastly, we use sed to remove the spaces that we added:

```
sed 's/ //g'
```

Note that this all could have been done with awk.  We could have broken up the input line into parts with `substr`.  With plain awk, we would have needed to write our own sorting routine or, if GNU awk was available, we could have used its builtin sort routine, `asort`.

Comment: It works perfectly! In addition, instead of using (...), is there any other ways   to separate the string? My real case would be hundreds of character in length.

Comment: Just got the answer:sed -r 's/(.{1})(.{4})(.{3})/\1 \2 \3/'

Comment: @WilliamLAM Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty terse:

```
sort -k 1.2,1.5 file | awk '{split($1, a, ""); sum=a[6]+a[7]+a[8]} sum > 0'
```